# Facebook - Fan page Tab & registration

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a site that require a social registration and login so I have set the facebook app and integrated it with Laravel and Socialite.

Now I need to allow users to visit the site and vote the images ( allowed only for registered user) in a facebook fun page tab.

Is it possibile? Can I use the same app id I have created for the social login or should I create another Tab app and include the facebook js sdk?

Which is the best workflow for this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sure is possible. One way to check if the user is logged in before visiting a route can be done like this. Example from Laravel 5.0

```
Route::get('facebook-fun-page-tab', ['middleware' => 'auth', function()
{
    // Only authenticated users may enter...
}]);

//Or if you use a controller
Route::get('facebook-fun-page-tab', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@show']);
```

And yes you could use the same facebook id.
More on [Laravel authentucation and protecting routes.](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication#protecting-routes)
More on [Middleware.](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/middleware)

One workflow is to do like this:
1. Login in the user/Register with facebook
2. After login, redirect user to Vote-image page